# Right approach to handle database requests

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I am trying to make a simple Test battle game where users compete with each other. When user clicks the **Start** button it first checks if there's available user on **is_available** table if there's then row's get deleted and game begins. If not that users data is put on the row. (simply there will be only one row available)  My question is, is this logic will work  when there are lots of requests at the same time? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should google about `Queue System`.

```
        struct BankCustomer
        {
            internal string name;
            internal string bankingActivity;
            internal int accountNumber;
            internal float amount;
        }
        enum BankingActivity
        { deposit, withdrawl, transferFunds }
        Queue localBankQueue = new Queue();
        private BankCustomer localBankCustomer;

        localBankCustomer.name = "J P Morgan";
    localBankCustomer.bankingActivity = BankingActivity.deposit.ToString();
    localBankCustomer.accountNumber = 335445;
    localBankCustomer.amount = 5600.00F;

//call this on click
localBankQueue.Enqueue(localBankCustomer);
```

Check this link out : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16838/The-Use-of-Queues-in-C

Answer (score 2):

instead of deleting; you can add a time aspect and clean out the table with records older than 6 hours past in GMT/UTC time. You want to go that route because US timezones you will have to check for day light savings time, while in UTC time you wont. From a tech point of view, DELETES keep logging to trans log; so even though your table will have no rows or data your trans log would have grown from previous deletes.